# Query not selecting all rows in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

******EDIT********

Sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63bd9/1)

******EDIT********

I am trying to join data from four different tables.

Essentially the system flow is as follows: a user logs in and marks their availability, which is inserted to the database; an admin is then able to view which users are available on any given date. For this particular process, the admin must be able to see available users who are not already appointed to a game.

I know this would achievable via PHP using a number of queries and scripting, but I'm sure this is also manageable via joins.

My existing query is:

```
SELECT
    `availability`.`ref_num`,
    `referee`.`grading`,
    `referee`.`user_number`,
    `user`.`forename`,
    `user`.`surname`,
    `availability`.`availability_num`,
    `availability`.`wk_num`,
    `availability`.`day_num`
FROM `availability`
INNER JOIN referee on availability.ref_num = referee.ref_number
INNER JOIN user on user.user_number = referee.user_number
LEFT JOIN appointments ON 
    (appointments.referee_code = referee.ref_number) AND 
    (appointments.availability_number = availability.availability_num)
WHERE appointments.appointment_number IS null
```

I have four users currently entered to my test db, each of these are a referee, and each of these have two available dates. However, the query above only returns two rows, rather than eight.

The returned data is:

```
ref_num  grading  user_number  forename  surname  availability_num  wk_num  day_num
3        5        6            John      Smith    72                20      6
3        5        6            John      Smith    73                21      6
```

However, I would be expecting:

```
ref_num  grading  user_number  forename  surname  availability_num  wk_num  day_num
1        6        3            Bob       Wills    76                20      6
1        6        3            Bob       Wills    77                21      6
2        7        5            Alex      Jones    74                20      6
2        7        5            Alex      Jones    75                21      6
3        5        6            John      Smith    72                20      6
3        5        6            John      Smith    73                21      6
4        8        7            James     Bar      78                20      6
4        8        7            James     Bar      79                21      6
```

I have a feeling that the two rows that actually are returned are because these are the lowest two values in `availability_num`, but I'm unable to work out why the rest of the tables aren't returned.

The table structures are below for reference. Some guidance as to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated. Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to present all of the information I had available.

```
`appointments` (
  `appointment_number` int(11),
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `referee_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fixture_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `availability_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `published` int(11) NOT NULL
)

`availability` (
  `availability_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wk_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_num` int(11) NOT NULL
)

`referee` (
  `ref_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grading` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_number` int(11) NOT NULL
)

`user` (
  `user_number` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `forename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_phone_number` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_phone_number` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_hash` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: tried removing the `where` clause?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it without the `where`, and also without the `left join` (and consequently the `where` too). It's quite frustrating.

Comment: Try making both INNER JOIN s LEFT JOIN s, you should start seeing data and NULL where the data most likely is missing / doesn't match

Comment: @Strawberry he is filtering on NULL... though I usually use HAVING, just because it seems more fitting to me.

Comment: Oops. Stepping away from the pc

Comment: Please set up a SQL Fiddle with the data.  Perhaps those are the right two rows to return and you are making a mistake in your interpretations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fiddle added by request, thanks for the suggestion. Matt.

Comment: Here is the catch your table availability column ref_num has value (3, 3, 5, 5, 6) and your table  referee column ref_number has value (1, 2, 3, 4) after INNER on that two column result of query is only table with two rows... and there is where problem starts (so you should add some data in table availability with value 1, 2, 4 etc in ref_num)

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic - thanks for picking that out, I was storing user numbers, and not ref numbers. As with most things, the problem was with me!

Comment: Glad you figured out problem... and i'm glad that i could help a little.  I found it strange that you have some value in ref_num column and doesn't have them in referee table, that was a clue... when you provide all data it's much easier to find a problem. GL :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no real 'problem' so to speak here - I just had data in the wrong data in the right column.

Credit to Aleksandar Miladinovic for picking that one out.